# Ti.Media.showCamera() on fullscreen?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When I use `Ti.Media.showCamera()` with an overlay, the camera frame is fixed at the top so it remains a black stripe at the bottom.
But I need the camera's image was in full screen, and not only fastened at the top
I can not move it in any way.. does anyone know a solution?

This is my code:

```
Ti.Media.showCamera({
    allowEditing : false,
    overlay : $.overlay,//overlayView,
    showControls : false,
    mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO],
    autohide : false,
    transform: Ti.UI.create2DMatrix().scale(1)
});
```

[image]

Comment: what is the code for your overlay?

Comment: In the case of the image, the code is quite long.. but the problem also occurs if I use a simple view on the overlay, for example
`var overlayView = Ti.UI.createView({borderColor:"red});`

Answer (score 1):

So, this used to work ok in previous tiSDKs and/or iOS SDK targets.  Titanium uses an OLD method for its camera that apple has been trying to get rid of.  With iOS 10, apple removed the hook that Titanium was using to work around all this.

It was reported and, right or wrong, was dismissed as not a titanium problem.(https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24036)

You can use Mike Fogg's module (https://github.com/mikefogg/SquareCamera) to achieve the look you once had, because it uses the appropriate foundation classes for its media work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try this module!
I found this other ticket: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23910. I think that's my problem.

Comment: Once I'd to create a simple iOS/android app witch includes a fullscreen camera with the torch light always on, I'd to use Mike Fogg's module to achieve the required result. If we can control the take picture, start/stop recording and the torch, and use an overlay view, we can accomplish any result. I've created 2 JIRA tickets: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23856 and https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23848

Comment: My question is: from now on, the camera will always appear like that?